# Is it possible to manually refresh Visual Studio 2019 IntelliSense DB for Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio, package, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

I have seen in multiple answers on Stack Overflow mentions about **Refresh DB** button in IntelliSense section of Python Environments window in Visual Studio 2017 and earlier versions. However I can't find this section in VS 2019, therefore no such button.

Have to deal with 2 libraries with identical names, and only restarting VS 2 times resolved IntelliSense not seeing the newly installed library (installing via VS environment packages). Is there a way to manually refresh IntelliSense in VS 2019?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to manually refresh IntelliSense in VS 2019?

I think you cannot get what you want in VS2019 and the question which you ask make sense.

In `VS2017 version 15.5` or before, **Microsoft** team added a manual refresh **Intellisense database** to improve performance. 
But since then, the team has dropped the button for other reasons. You can see it from [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/editing-python-code-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#intellisense).

**However**, there are some other communtiy members has raised [this issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/729602/python-intellisense-does-not-update-until-restart.html) and **Microsoft** said they were working on it.

In order to get the attention of Microsoft as soon as possible, I have reported [this problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/931183/cannot-get-the-button-refresh-intellisense-db-for.html) to the **DC Forum** for you. You can add any comments which contains any detailed info in this link.

**Besides**, anyone who is interested in this issue will see it and then vote it to draw Microsoft's attention.

While you're waiting, you can only restart the project as multiple times as you described.

Comment: Not sure whether this does work. 1) You can unable the option `Track changes` under

`Tools`->`Options`->`Text Editor`->`General`  2) close vs instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the physcial path of the solution, then restart your project.

Comment: Thank you for your time and for your research. I don't think I will encounter this problem again soon, it only happened to the "extension" package with the same name (not sure how to call it, it was Curses package for Windows, as the standard one is not available for Windows). Gonna check the links right now.